"Base" set in mathematical induction
I am reading Naive Set Theory by Paul Halmos and trying to solve the exercise: Prove that the union of a finite set of finite sets is finite.
Here's my attempt at the proof:
Let $S$ be the set of all natural numbers $n$ such that for any set $N$ of finite sets such that $\#(N) = n$, the union of $N$ is finite.
First, let's assert that the only set that is equivalent to $0 = \{\}$ is $\emptyset = 0$ itself.
Suppose that there is a set $A$ that is not $\{\}$ and equivalent to $0$, then there must be an element $a \in A$ and there must exists a one-to-one correspondence $f$ between $A$ and $0$. We then have $f(a) \in 0$ and thus, $0$ is not empty, which is a contradiction to the very definition of $0$. So there is no such $A$.
Now, we have $\cup \{\} = \{\}$, and $\{\} \sim 0$, so $0 \in S$.
Suppose $n \in S$. We have $n^{+} = n \cup \{n\}$. Let $A$ be an arbitrary set that is equivalent to $n^{+}$, and let $g$ be the one-to-one correspondence from $A$ to $n^{+}$. Since $n \in n^{+}$ and $g$ is a one-to-one correspondence, let $a$ be an element in $A$ that $g(a) = n$.
We have $A = (A - \{a\}) \cup \{a\}$. Since $g$ is a one-to-one correspondence, so any $x \in A - \{a\}$ will have $g(x) \not = g(a)$ or $g(x) \not = n$. Thus, if we restrict $g$ to $A - \{a\}$ only, we have a one-to-one correspondence between $A - \{a\}$ and $n$. So $A - \{a\} \sim n$.
We then have $\cup A = \cup (A - \{a\}) \cup a$. Since $A - \{a\} \sim n$, $\cup (A - \{a\})$ is finite. Since $a$ is also finite, $\cup A = \cup (A - \{a\}) \cup a$ is finite.
So $n^{+} \in S$ and $S = \omega$ (the natural numbers set).
The problem I have with this proof is that in the very beginning, the book shows that nothing contains everything (or no set contains everything); then, how exactly $S$ exists in the first place when we cannot specify "all" the set that is supposed to be checked for each element of $\omega$ so that it can be verified to belong to $S$. I have search for the proof on the Internet and found that the first proof on the Wikipedia page is very similar to mine. So I think there must be some problem with my understanding of the "base" set of induction.

I would have thought you would want to show that the union of two finite sets was finite and then use induction to show  the union of a finite number of finite sets was finite.

Your $S$ is a well-defined subset of $\omega$.

@Henry I have already proven that and used it later in my proof for this problem

@AnneBauval I am aware of that. However, the axiom of specification states that to every set $A$ and to every condition $S(x)$, there corresponds a set $B$ whose elements are exactly those elements $x$ of $A$ for which $S(x)$ holds. In my case, I took $A= \omega$, but I am uncertain about the validity of my $S(x)$ condition. Specifically, my concern is whether $S(x)$ can be well-defined if it requires checking over "all" sets to verify the condition. Could you clarify if this is consistent with the axiom of specification?

Finite Union of Finite Sets is Finite

There is no problem: by the axiom schema of specification
$$S=\{n\in\omega\mid S(n)\},$$
is a set, where the predicate $S(n)$ is
$$\forall N\quad(N\sim n\land\forall x\in N\quad\operatorname{Fin}(x))\implies \operatorname{Fin}(\cup N),$$
$\operatorname{Fin}(x)$ being an abbreviation for $\exists k\in\omega\quad x\sim k$,
$x\sim y$ being itself an abbreviation for (some predicate meaning) "there exists a bijection from $x$ onto $y$".

Thank you. So it turns out we can refer to the entirety of something without needing to define a specific set that includes it.
